# Request to merge tags [android-mediacodec] and [mediacodec]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I have spotted two separate tags related to Android programming:

[android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec)
[mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec)

I think they should be merged into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tags do indeed represent the same thing and should be merged. It seems reasonable to use the older and more established one as a merge base, but I think it should be renamed to [android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec) afterward, as prefixing `android-*` to the tag is a prevalent naming convention (see detailed [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=android-), [totals](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266064/totals-for-tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=android-&starts=1) query):

> 691 tags of which 470 have an excerpt and 404 have a wiki

**Proposal**

1. Use tag wiki from [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec) as it is more detailed
2. Merge [android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec) into [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec)
3. Rename [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec) to [android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec) to respect naming convention

Comment: I agree with your proposal. Do we need extra discussion with other members? Who can realize merge?

Comment: @404pio - thank you - no, nothing else is needed, if anyone has any reservations, they will post here or comment. Then, once a moderator passes by and they have time to spare and no concerns, then a merge will be enacted and your question will be marked [tag:status-complete] (be prepared that it might take a while).

Comment: @404pio Although a invite to the top answerers/subject experts wouldn't hurt either. So, that there are no objections post merge

Comment: @TheMaster - I agree, that's usually a good idea to do when changing the status quo ( which is not widely adopted in [tag:retag-request]s for some reason ). This case can probably forgo this part safely, though, they are basically the same tag, and the answerers usually benefit from merge (but in burnination and synonym requests I think it should be a must)

Answer (score 2):

This is an obviously appropriate merge, so further discussion is not really necessary.

Prior to the merge, there were only 5 questions in total that were tagged [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec) but not also tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Of those 5:

- Two were clearly about Android, based either on the title or on the presence of version-specific tags, and I've added the general [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag to both of those questions, as it should have been there since the beginning.
- Two were ambiguous to me. I'm not sure if they are about Android, and definitely not sure if they are about Android MediaCodec. I could use some help retagging these:

  - [MediaCodec Decoder issues with dequeueOutputBuffer call (H.264)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929147/mediacodec-decoder-issues-with-dequeueoutputbuffer-call-h-264)
  - [What is the color type that i get from Buffer, using MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612883/what-is-the-color-type-that-i-get-from-buffer-using-mediacodec)
- [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387318/video-what-is-i-frames-and-do-they-affect-the-video-size) was a general question about media codecs, and not about either Android or Android MediaCodec. I went ahead and retagged this.

So this is now done:

[android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec) ← [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec)

I've also merged in the tag wiki, so that [android-mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediacodec) has the best information from both.

The [android-*] prefixed tag is being used as the primary tag, following the standard convention for Android technology tags. This should also discourage misuse of the [mediacodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediacodec) tag for general questions about media codecs.